# Fixed size swing GUI changes when using different resolution

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, resolution

I have a small java application with a swing gui. I have set a fixed size for the window and everything works really well. But when using the GUI on different screens, the objects seem to have moved slightly. (Labels not showing their entire text etc,...) I think the difference lies in the aspect ratio of the screen but is there any way to counter this?

Comment: That's why you should not set layout manager to null and why using fixed size is bad idea.

Comment: Are you sure the fonts are identical, including DPI settings? As Bryan Oakley points out, you shouldn't be using fixed size windows. They break when the fonts change. They break if you internationalize. There are probably other things that can go wrong. Use a layout manager.

Comment: OscarRyz gave me the winning tip, did some searching, tried using the MiGLayout manager and everything is much better now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to counter it is to not used fixed size windows.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Bryan. There are many reasons - the screen resolution, localization (if you do so), different look-and-feels and rendering depending on the platform and/or JVM version. Swing's layouts are flexible enough to do everything you want without fixing the frame size. Otherwise you are going to implement your rendering engine to calculate *everything* which is rendered.

Comment: @I82Much thanks. It would be better if people leave comments when voting down.